# Python Tkinter Telescope: Generate a continuous updating image preview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am still learning Python-3 codes.

My goal is to take Pi Camera "preview" or image.jpg and continuous update that picture on a Tkinter GUI frame. So you can see what image would look like before you commit to save a jpg from Telescope.

The code below can't find a simple file that was already there in the same folder location as 'image.jpg'. Also the problem is that this would end up a static old image. Is there a way to make that part of code run on a loop?

The Pi Camera itself can take a new image and create a jpg file at /home/pi just fine. The main program is also located at /home/pi. Every time I run the program it print out "Image not found" under Try.

```
from Tkinter import *
import picamera

root = Tk() #makes the window
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
root.wm_title("Camera GUI Program") #Makes the title that will appear in the top left
root.config(background = "#FFFFFF") #Sets background color to white

def redCircle():
    circleCanvas.create_oval(20,20,80,80,width = 0, fill='red')
    colorLog.insert(0.0, "Red\n")

def yelCircle():
    circleCanvas.create_oval(20, 20, 80, 80, width=0, fill='green')
    colorLog.insert(0.0, "Green\n")


#Left Frame and its contents
leftFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height = 600)
leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

Label(leftFrame, text="Instructions:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

Instruct = Label(leftFrame, text="1\n2\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n")
Instruct.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

try:
    camera.capture('image.jpg')
    imageEx = PhotoImage(file = 'image.jpg')
    Label(leftFrame, image=imageEx).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
except:
    print("Image not found")

#Right Frame and its contents
rightFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height = 600)
rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

circleCanvas = Canvas(rightFrame, width=100, height=100, bg='white')
circleCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

btnFrame = Frame(rightFrame, width=200, height = 200)
btnFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

colorLog = Text(rightFrame, width = 30, height = 10, takefocus=0)
colorLog.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

redBtn = Button(btnFrame, text="Red", command=redCircle)
redBtn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

yellowBtn = Button(btnFrame, text="Yellow", command=yelCircle)
yellowBtn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

greenBtn = Button(btnFrame, text="Green", command=grnCircle)
greenBtn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=2)

root.mainloop() #start monitoring and updating the GUI. Nothing below here runs.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], above code is rather short. But it can lose some redundant parts for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the error is thrown because the file is not found? You have 3 possible statements under the try that could trip the exception. You need to find out which one is causing the error. For paths, try using full path.

As to the loop. Typically, a function is created and then repeatedly schedules itself on the event loop using the `after` command.

```
pwd = os.getcwd()
imageEx = PhotoImage(file=pwd + '/image.jpg')
label_image = Label(leftframe, image=imageEx)
label_image.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
label_image.image = imageEx

def picapture():
    global label_image, root, pwd
    try:
        camera.capture('image.jpg')
        imageEx = PhotoImage(file=pwd + '/image.jpg')
        # Only update the image displayed by the label.
        label_image.image = imageEx
        # Schedule picature function to run every 1000 milliseconds
        root.after(1000, picapture)
    except:
        print("Image not found")

...
picapture()
```

Comment: I made a few more adjustment and it is now saying "__tkinter.TcLError: couldn't recognize data in image file "/home/pi/image.jpg""

Comment: Oops. Left that out. You need to (install and) import PIL to work with JPEG images. So try `from PIL import Image`, then `imageEx = Image.open(pwd + '/image.jpg')`.

Comment: I double checked that I have pillow (PIL right?) and it say the version is already installed. It goes back to image not found.

Comment: Yes pillow is PIL. If you still have multiple commands under the `try`, you should make sure that the exception is clear when thrown. You were overriding the python exception that would ordinarily be raised. You can do multiple things to find out what the problem is. Here is one. Import traceback. Then in the exception block replace your current print statement with `print(traceback.format_exc(limit=10))` or use whatever line limit you prefer. It should tell you exactly which line is the culprit.

Comment: it said "PermissionError: [Errno 13]: Permission denied: 'image.jpg'". I tried to change the file's permission a bit around. No luck. For example: Set all permission to anyone via image.jpg's properties.

Comment: Your next steps should include file permissions and/or system administration functions. Check file and directory ownership, noting that the permissions of the python script. In any case, the problem you're running into now is less related to python than permissions.